# Get the start_date when the user clicks a button in Django?

Tags: django

I am trying to get the start_date and end_date(after processing finishes) in Django. I have a simple form. When user clicks `Submit` I want to get the start_date and insert that value into the database. After processing completes I want to get the end_date and insert that value into the database. I have already setup the database in Django. The processing is done as:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

How do I know when the command execution finishes and record the end_date?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`Popen.poll()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll). It will return None while the Popen is still executing. By example:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.now()
c = subprocess.Popen (["find", "/home/whatever", "-name","eclipse.ini"])

while c.poll() is None:
    pass

deltatime = datetime.now() - d1
print deltatime.total_seconds()
```

Be careful with the `while` loop. Your program will be stuck in it until the Popen process ends. Maybe you want to launch a thread to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do it the elegant way, you should try using an asynchronous task system like [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/index.html), and execute your bash process inside a task like César García presented.

Another option is to execute something like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sshpass ... && curl -X GET IP:PORT/some/internal/view/%d/' % task_id], shell=True)
```

The finish time may be inserted to the database inside the django view.